# Passing a javascript variable in Ajax to a Java class

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I am passing a javscript variable to a java class. I am not sure if this is consider a proper way, if so is my syntax correct and how can i make sure that the variable has passed successfully to my java class?

```
var key = record.getKey();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "apps/APP/src/Test.java",
    data: {id : key},
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sending "the variable"  to a web application written in Java? If you're trying to send something via Ajax to a Java file (as I think that's exactly the case), you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @juliobetta how should i do it?

Comment: First off, is this a web application written in Java? If not, it should be!

Comment: Let me explain. Ajax calls can be made to web based applications only. There's no way to send something to a plain java class. Here's a thorough explanation on how ajax works [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: @juliobetta it is a web application written in Java

Comment: what api is the Java based web app using? It looks like you're trying to post to the source file, which is not going to work. What apis is this source file using, and how/where is it running? is it a servlet, is it running on a servlet container?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>A simple Java Class cannot handle an Ajax request (or any web request for that matter) You should be having a Java Web application/ Dynamic Web Application, either written with vanilla `Servlets and JSP` or using any frameworks like `spring` to handle web  requests.This application must be deployed on a `Servlet Container` like `Tomcat` or `Jetty`.</strike>

[This](http://www.journaldev.com/1854/java-web-application-tutorial-for-beginners)  tutorial should get you started as its too broad to be covered in a SO answer. Do get back with a new question if you face any issues.

Updated as per your comment:

Since you have a Dynamic Web Application It should have a Servlet, and as your Ajax request is using POST method, override the `doPost()` and get the data from request object. *Note: Use POST only if you are mutating some data in the backend else use GET.*

Please see the below code.

```
   public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
      public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
          {
              request.getParameter("id"); //use the key of the json data you need
          }

    }
```

Comment: It is a dynamic web project deployed on tomcat

Comment: So you should be having a servlet that need the data from the Javascript, right ?